# Get escaped html from td and put it into input as value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html

```
<table>
<tr><td id="cell">&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;Google.com&lt;/a&gt;</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="to"></div>
```

And I have javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var html = '<input type="text" value="'+$("#cell").html()+'" />'
   $("#to").append(html);
});
```

I don't know why, but when executing this code I'm getting only `<a href=` in input. In firebug's inspector input html appears as `<input type="text" a&gt;="" &gt;google.com&lt;="" value="&lt;a href=" >` As you can see, `$quot;` are replaced with `"` - this is the problem.

I've tried using `.text()` instead of `.html()` - almost the same situation.

What is my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: This may not be relevant but you can use textarea instead of a textbox,  it accepts a newline though.

Comment: @jerjer: a textarea is no different to a single-line input. You must `&`-escape any HTML-special characters in it just the same. Browsers let you get away with slightly worse invalid code in a textarea than an input, but you shouldn't be relying on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('<input type="text">').val($("#cell").html()).appendTo("#to");
});
```

Avoid building HTML from strings and variables, use the functions jQuery and the DOM give to you to assign values to attributes or change an element's text. It's safer this way, and IMHO it's more readable as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to encode the value (set via [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in this case), not use it directly in a string, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var html = $('<input type="text" />').val($("#cell").html());
   $("#to").append(html);
});
```

[You can see it in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/gtZhe/). The problem is the `&quote;` gets decoded to `"` which is making your HTML look like this:

```
<input type="text" value="&lt;a href=""&gt;Google.com&lt;/a&gt;" />
```

You can see how that makes the browser a little crazy :)

Comment: I would guess it should be `val(...text())` here rather than `html()`? Unless the user really wants to see `&lt;` in the input value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write customize function to unescape the string

```
function unescape(html) {
  return html.
    replace(/&amp;/gmi, '&').
    replace(/&quot;/gmi, '"').
    replace(/&gt;/gmi, '>').
    replace(/&lt;/gmi, '<')
}
```

Comment: That is not recommendable. HTML parsing involves a bit more than replacing a few strings, and functions like one this usually make it worse somewhere down the road.

Comment: And there is no guarantee that the browser will choose to `&`-escape those-and-only-those characters when producing `html()`. The exact format of an `innerHTML` can't be relied on.